# How do I connect to Google Cloud SQL from Google Compute Engine in production?

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a web application running on Google Compute Engine. I am currently running MySQL on a regular instance, and I want to migrate to Cloud SQL for scalability and reliability.

[The GCE docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/compute-engine-access) describe how to connect by Internet IP address or the Cloud SQL Proxy to run the MySQL client to configure a database. They do not describe how to connect to Cloud SQL for a "production" environment that needs to reliably handle a large volume of queries. The Cloud SQL Proxy seems like an elegant solution, because I prefer not to assign external IP addresses to the web servers (they are behind a load balancer), or send database traffic over the Internet.

1. Which method(s) are considered "production-ready" for connecting a web server to a Cloud SQL instance?
2. Is Cloud SQL Proxy suitable for a production application?
3. Is traffic encrypted between the Cloud SQL Proxy and Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Either direct connection by IP or via Cloud SQL Proxy.

2) Yes, the Cloud SQL Proxy is production ready.

3) Yes, the connection between the Cloud SQL Proxy and the Cloud SQL instance happens over SSL.